# Inject variable to isolated scope of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to inject variable from outer scope to isolated scope of directive without explicit definition of attribute?

```
directive:
  scope:
    attr: '='

div(directive, attr="var1", inject-to-scope="someObject")
```

Little bit similar to `scope: true`.

Comment: I don't think you can, if you declare scope in your directive you got a clean new scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible.**
A directive can have its own controller and in that one, you can inject whatever you like, to make it accessable **in** the isolated scope of the directive. (not **in** the directives code)

```
yourApp.directive('yourDirective', function(OUTSIDE) {
return {
       templateUrl: 'template.html',
       scope: {},
       controller: function($scope){
           $scope.outside = OUTSIDE
       }
    };
});
```

So 'OUTSIDE' could be a service, a constant, anykind of object . . .
And as normal, the scope which is defined by the controller will be accessable in your template like this:

```
<div>This box is isolated, but able to look {{outside}}</div>
```